# Typescript compiler did not flagged for function returning Any when --noImplicitAny is set

Tags: typescript

Why is the following code not throwing any error during compilation using `tsc` with `--noImplicitAny` turned on when the function `test` is returning a value of type Any?

I don't think in this context the compiler is able to infer the type of the return value of the function since depends on the if else, the return type is different.

```
function test(str: string)
{
    if(str === "b")
    {
        return "abcd";
    }
    else
    {
        return 5;
    }
}


console.log(typeof(test("b"));
console.log(typeof(test("c"));
```

Comment: Tried restarting ts server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no implicit `any`, the function signature can be inferred as:

```
function test(str: string): "abcd" | 5
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygCgwJwFyK4xgDmAlIgN4BQidiA9AwHoD8t9Mwi2UOiAXiGIARACMRFGvRmIcKKCBxIRAQzEQAJiIDcHOgF99iFABs0KKsZnzFyxAFY9Mo0aA)

Comment: Ok I got it. I didn't know typescript supports returning value of multiple types.